# MIPS assembly function type call in C

Tags: assembly, mips, reverse-engineering

I stuck on trying to figure out what type of a function the subroutine_fnc in C is supposed to be and what parameters it is supposed to have. I know it has 1 paramter, which is also an address but I'm stuck beyond this point. Any help or tips on how I should proceed to figure it out would be great.

```
00405344 <toplevel_fnc>:
  405344:   27bdffc8    addiu   sp,sp,-56
  405348:   afbf0034    sw  ra,52(sp)
  40534c:   afbe0030    sw  s8,48(sp)
  405350:   03a0f025    move    s8,sp
  405354:   1000001e    b   4053d0 <toplevel_fnc+0x8c>
  405358:   00000000    nop
  40535c:   83c20028    lb  v0,40(s8)
  405360:   00000000    nop
  405364:   00402025    move    a0,v0
  405368:   0c1014b0    jal 4052c0 <subroutine_fnc>
  40536c:   00000000    nop
  405370:   00021600    sll v0,v0,0x18
  405374:   00021603    sra v0,v0,0x18
  405378:   a3c20028    sb  v0,40(s8)
  40537c:   24040001    li  a0,1
  405380:   27c20028    addiu   v0,s8,40
  405384:   00402825    move    a1,v0
  405388:   24060001    li  a2,1
  40538c:   24020fa4    li  v0,4004
  405390:   0000000c    syscall
  405394:   afc70018    sw  a3,24(s8)
  405398:   afc20024    sw  v0,36(s8)
  40539c:   8fc20018    lw  v0,24(s8)
  4053a0:   00000000    nop
  4053a4:   14400004    bnez    v0,4053b8 <toplevel_fnc+0x74>
  4053a8:   00000000    nop
  4053ac:   8fc20024    lw  v0,36(s8)
  4053b0:   10000002    b   4053bc <toplevel_fnc+0x78>
  4053b4:   00000000    nop
  4053b8:   2402ffff    li  v0,-1
  4053bc:   afc20020    sw  v0,32(s8)
  4053c0:   8fc20020    lw  v0,32(s8)
  4053c4:   00000000    nop
  4053c8:   04400018    bltz    v0,40542c <toplevel_fnc+0xe8>
  4053cc:   00000000    nop
  4053d0:   00002025    move    a0,zero
  4053d4:   27c20028    addiu   v0,s8,40
  4053d8:   00402825    move    a1,v0
  4053dc:   24060001    li  a2,1
  4053e0:   24020fa3    li  v0,4003
  4053e4:   0000000c    syscall
  4053e8:   afc70018    sw  a3,24(s8)
  4053ec:   afc2001c    sw  v0,28(s8)
  4053f0:   8fc20018    lw  v0,24(s8)
  4053f4:   00000000    nop
  4053f8:   14400004    bnez    v0,40540c <toplevel_fnc+0xc8>
  4053fc:   00000000    nop
  405400:   8fc2001c    lw  v0,28(s8)
  405404:   10000002    b   405410 <toplevel_fnc+0xcc>
  405408:   00000000    nop
  40540c:   2402ffff    li  v0,-1
  405410:   afc20020    sw  v0,32(s8)
  405414:   8fc30020    lw  v1,32(s8)
  405418:   24020001    li  v0,1
  40541c:   1062ffcf    beq v1,v0,40535c <toplevel_fnc+0x18>
  405420:   00000000    nop
  405424:   10000002    b   405430 <toplevel_fnc+0xec>
  405428:   00000000    nop
  40542c:   00000000    nop
  405430:   3c020041    lui v0,0x41
  405434:   8c426190    lw  v0,24976(v0)
  405438:   03c0e825    move    sp,s8
  40543c:   8fbf0034    lw  ra,52(sp)
  405440:   8fbe0030    lw  s8,48(sp)
  405444:   27bd0038    addiu   sp,sp,56
  405448:   03e00008    jr  ra
  40544c:   00000000    nop

program data
```

Comment: Well the `v0` register is used to store the return value of some function and the return value of the toplevel_fnc is int but i could be understanding it wrong

Comment: I think I might be confused by the `lb` instruction. I'm not really sure what happens when `move a0,v0` is called here

Comment: Yes, in the standard calling convention, `a0..a3` hold the incoming function args (parameters), and `v0`/`v1` hold return values.  Your question is asking about args, not return values, so `v0` is just another scratch register on entry to the function.

Comment: The parameter is definitely not an address since it's loaded using `lb`. Looks like it's `char subroutine_fnc(char)`. I have not checked the syscall numbers but I guess it's reading a character, transforming it and writing it out.

Comment: Oh, I was looking at the whole `toplevel_fnc` (which I think doesn't take any args), but you're asking about a function it calls.  My bad.  Yes, this debug build loads into `v0` and then copies to `a0`, because it's probably GCC `-O0` output.  So it's passing a signed 8-bit value as an arg to `subroutine_fnc` (sign-extended to a full register.)

Comment: How would you know it is a char? Is it because of the 4004 syscall (write)

Comment: It's because the `lb` and `sb` operate on bytes. It could of course be any type that is a single signed byte, but `char` is most likely.

Comment: I see, but how do I find out what `char` I am actually passing to `subroutine_fnc`? Basically I don't understand what the `subroutine_fnc` does here. It just looks to me as if it is called and does nothing.

Comment: The char the other syscall (presumably a read) has returned.

Comment: Ah right yeah. Also, after the second syscall (read) there is an instrunction `sw a3,24(28)`. I don't quite understand what this is meant to do.

Comment: I assume the syscall convention uses that to return an error code. To quote a  [wiki](https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Syscall): _"The result value is returned in $v0 and $a3 will be set to 0 or 1 to indicate success."_

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. Last question before I should be able to finish: `sw a3,24(s8)`, `sw v0,28(s8)`, `lw v0,24(s8)`. Is this basically just `v0=a3` and store old `v0` at `28(s8)`?

Comment: Yes, just some useless shuffling around of registers due to unoptimized code.